# Error in Linked List Insertion at last position

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, data-structures

I coded a Linked List Insertion program in C++. When I added a function to insert a node at the last position of the linked list, I am getting a weird output. It seems like the address is being outputted. This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
   int data;
   Node *next;
   Node(int d)
   {
     data=d;
   }
};

class operations
{
public:
    Node *head;
    Node *ptr;

    void insertfirst(int d)
    {
        Node *newnode = new Node(d);
        newnode->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            head=newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            newnode->next=head;
            head=newnode;
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        Node *ptr;
        ptr=head;
        while(ptr!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
    }

    void insertafter(int key, int d)
    {
        Node *ptr;
        ptr=head;
        while(ptr->data!=key)
        {
            if(ptr->next==NULL)
            {
                cout<<"Key not found";
                return;
            }
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        Node *newnode=new Node(d);
        newnode->next=ptr->next;
        ptr->next=newnode;
    }

    void insertlast(int d)
    {
        Node *ptr;
        ptr=head;
        Node *newnode = new Node(d);
        newnode->next=NULL;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
        {
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next=newnode;
    }
};

int main()
{
    operations o;
    o.insertfirst(4);
    o.insertfirst(3);
    o.insertafter(3,5);
    o.insertlast(1);
    o.display();
    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
3 5 4 1577825 1
```

My expected output is:

```
3 5 4 1
```

What should I do to get my expected output?

Comment: If the goal is a linked list, why is the class called operations? And what does this have to do with DSA?

Comment: The code, as provided, just crashes with a segmentation fault for me.

Comment: Make sure you handle the `head` node correctly if `insertlast()` is called first  (hint, you really need a constructor for `operations` that initializes `head = nullptr;` and you need to check if `head == nullptr;` before you attempt to derefernce `head` by accessing the `->next` pointer. If you add a `tail` pointer, you will avoid having to iterate in `insertlast()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not see any problem with logic, and i think your code should be fixed by removing the public "Node *ptr;" variable definition. In other words, you may only need to add this variable locally in all of your fuctions.

Also it would be a better practice if you initialized the node->next =null inside Node constructor.
Here is your code with discussed modifictions.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
   public:
   int data;
   Node *next;
   Node()
   {
     data=INT_MAX;
     next= NULL;
   }
   Node(int d)
   {
     data=d;
     next= NULL;
   }
};
    class operations
    {
        public:
        Node *head;
        operations() {
            head =NULL;
        }
        void insertfirst(int d)
        {
            Node *newnode = new Node(d);
        
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            head=newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            newnode->next=head;
            head=newnode;
        }
        
    }
    void display()
    {
        
        Node *ptr;
        ptr=head;
        
        while(ptr)
        {
            cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        
    }
    void insertafter(int key, int d)
    {
        Node *ptr;
        ptr=head;
        while(ptr->data!=key)
        {
            if(ptr->next==NULL)
            {
                cout<<"Key not found";
                return;
            }
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        Node *newnode=new Node(d);
        newnode->next=ptr->next;
        ptr->next=newnode;
    }
    void insertlast(int d)
    {
        Node *ptr;
        ptr=head;
        Node *newnode = new Node(d);
        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
        {
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next=newnode;
    }
};
int main() {
    operations o;
    o.insertfirst(4);
    o.insertfirst(3);
    o.insertafter(3,5);
    o.insertlast(1);
    o.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always initialize `newnode->next = nullptr;` after node creation -- it will save lots of grief...

Comment: @David C. Rankin, agreed, but as mentioned it would be much more better if this process will be done inside constructor of Node class.

Comment: Which you don't do correctly. At a minimum, use the initialization section of the ctor, better would be default member initialization.

Comment: "*I do not see any problem with logic*" - really? Because I see a few.

Comment: I mean, if there weren't any, it would be working.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, great, do not hesitate to share them!!!

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to deal with such problems.

- Run your program in a debugger. This is usually the quickest way to solve complex problems, so you should plan to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger soon. Since the debugger is a quite complex tool and many of the popular debuggers out there are not that straightforward to use, you may not want to use one for this particular problem. In the long term though: Learn how to use a debugger.
- Run your program on paper. Especially for linked lists, this approach is pure gold. Draw the nodes on paper, and draw arrows for tracking which pointer points to what. Then go through your program line by line and update the drawing as you go along. It's important that you don't cut corners here and really go line by line, meticulously retracing the individual steps of the program, even if it seems tedious at first. The problem should reveal itself rather quickly this way. If you still get stuck, add additional debug output to your code as sanity checks that your paper simulation was indeed accurate. If you did make a mistake on paper, the additional output should help you catch it.

Since the second approach requires a bit of manual labor, it often pays off to reduce the program that exhibits the bad behavior as much as possible. For instance, do you still see the problem if you remove the line `o.insertfirst(3);` from `main`? Can you remove any more lines before the problem disappears?

Once you narrowed down the error in this way, grab a piece of paper and give it a go. Don't be afraid of the work, fixing bugs this way is the bread and butter of software engineering and this particular problem is an excellent exercise for sharpening your skills in that regard.

Happy bug hunting!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in your function `insertfirst()`. You don't consistently initialize all members of your node, so when you add that first node with value 4, `head` is not always `NULL` (use `nullptr` with C++), so you have your node with value 4 point to a garbage pointer.

As mentioned in the other answer, stepping through the code with a debugger would have revealed this very quickly.

C++ has come a long way, stop treating it like C. Use constructors (along with default member initialization), name your list class `List` instead of operations. Actually encapsulate your data. Learn about the Rule of 3/5/0. Learn about iterators. A proper linked list in C++ is a culmination of a *lot* of principles and patterns.

=== OPTIONAL ===

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

/*
 * List Declaration
 */
class List {
 public:
  List() = default;         // Default constructor
  List(const List& other);  // Copy ctor
  List(List&& other);       // Move ctor
  ~List();                  // Destructor

  // Iterators are an invaluable design pattern; they allow your class to
  // interact with the Standard Library
  class iterator;
  iterator begin();
  iterator end();

  // Naming changed to better match Standard Library behavior
  void push_front(int val);
  void push_back(int val);
  iterator insert(iterator pos, int val);
  iterator find(int val);

  void clear();

  List& operator=(List rhs);
  friend void swap(List& lhs, List& rhs);

 private:
  struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next = nullptr;

    Node(int val) : data(val) {}
  };

  Node* m_head = nullptr;
  Node* m_tail = nullptr;

  // Helper functions
  void make_first_node(int val);
};

/*
 * List Iterator Declaration
 */
class List::iterator {
 public:
  iterator(Node* pos);
  int& operator*();
  iterator& operator++();
  bool operator==(iterator other);
  bool operator!=(iterator other);

 private:
  Node* m_pos;
};

/*
 * List Implementation
 */
List::List(const List& other) {
  make_first_node((other.m_head)->data);

  Node* walker = (other.m_head)->next;
  while (walker) {
    push_back(walker->data);
  }
}

List::List(List&& other) : List() { swap(*this, other); }

List::~List() { clear(); }

typename List::iterator List::begin() { return iterator(m_head); }

typename List::iterator List::end() { return iterator(nullptr); }

void List::push_front(int val) {
  if (!m_head) {
    make_first_node(val);
    return;
  }

  Node* tmp = new Node(val);
  tmp->next = m_head;
  m_head = tmp;
}

void List::push_back(int val) {
  if (!m_head) {
    make_first_node(val);
    return;
  }

  m_tail->next = new Node(val);
  m_tail = m_tail->next;
}

typename List::iterator List::insert(iterator pos, int val) {
  Node* walker = m_head;
  while (walker->next->data != *pos) {
    walker = walker->next;
  }

  Node* marker = walker->next;
  walker->next = new Node(val);
  walker->next->next = marker;

  return iterator(walker->next);
}

typename List::iterator List::find(int val) {
  Node* walker = m_head;
  while (walker) {
    if (walker->data == val) {
      return iterator(walker);
    } else {
      walker = walker->next;
    }
  }

  return iterator(walker);
}

void List::clear() {
  Node* tmp = m_head;
  while (tmp) {
    m_head = m_head->next;
    delete tmp;
    tmp = m_head;
  }
  m_tail = nullptr;
}

List& List::operator=(List rhs) {
  swap(*this, rhs);

  return *this;
}

void List::make_first_node(int val) {
  m_head = new Node(val);
  m_tail = m_head;
}

// List Friend
void swap(List& lhs, List& rhs) {
  using std::swap;

  swap(lhs.m_head, rhs.m_head);
  swap(lhs.m_tail, rhs.m_tail);
}

/*
 * List Iterator Implementation
 */
List::iterator::iterator(List::Node* pos) : m_pos(pos) {}

int& List::iterator::operator*() { return m_pos->data; }

typename List::iterator& List::iterator::operator++() {
  m_pos = m_pos->next;

  return *this;
}

bool List::iterator::operator==(typename List::iterator other) {
  return m_pos == other.m_pos;
}

bool List::iterator::operator!=(typename List::iterator other) {
  return !(*this == other);
}

int main() {
  List list;
  list.push_front(4);
  list.push_front(3);
  // My insert() behaves like the Standard Library's, meaning before & not after
  list.insert(list.find(4), 5);
  list.push_back(1);

  // The iterator implemented provides *just* enough functionality to allow
  // the class to be used in a range-based for loop
  for (auto i : list) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```